# Внедрение зависимостей в android без dagger2

Tags: android, архитектура

Написал каркас приложения, как мне кажется, следуя принципам clean architecture. Возник вопрос - как объединить части приложения без использования dagger2 и схожих инструментов? Вот так я вижу структуру приложения

```
// Layer UI

public class Activity implements IView {
    Presenter presenter;

    // Кто передает презентер в активити? Или пускай сама и создаёт?
}

// Layer Presenters

public class Presenter implements IPresentation{
    interface IView {
        // ...
    }

    Presenter(IView view, Command cmd1, Command cmd2) {
        // Кто ещё, кроме презентера, может знать о вьюхах и кейсах (точнее об их интерфейсах)?
    }
}

// Layer Use Cases
interface IPresentation {
    // ...
}

public interface Command {
    void execute();
}

public class Start implements Command {
    public Start(IPresentation presentation, Entity entity) {
        // Кто создает экземпляр этого класса?
    }

    public void execute() {
        // ...
    }
}


public class Stop implements Command {
    public Stop(IPresentation presentation, Entity entity) {
        // ...
    }

    public void execute() {
        // ...
    }
}

// Layer Repository

public class Repository {
    // В принципе, можно сделать методы статичными
    public Entity getEntity() {
        // ...
        return entity;
    }

    public void updateEntity(Entity entity) {
        // ...
    }
}

// Layer Entities

public class Entity {
    // Ну тут вопросов нет. Ничего не знает и знать не хочет о нашем приложении
}
```

Comment: Ваш вопрос о том как сделать свой аналог `dagger`-а или как сделать его работу на ином принципе?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, в принцип работы даггера я не вникал. Почитал о нём поверхностно и понял, что этот инструмент, скорее всего, предназначен для решения задачи, поставленной в вопросе. Перед тем как разбираться с даггером хотелось бы сделать его работу "руками".

Comment: Изучить паттерн dependency injection

Comment: @georgehardcore, по сути лучший ответ. Пролистал статью на вики - где то так сам и начал делать. Отдельный класс для инъекций и погнали.

Answer (score 2):

Возможно вам поможет статья https://arturdryomov.online/posts/a-dagger-to-remember/ от Juno (там сделано на Kotlin, в нем есть удобные инструменты чтобы писать меньше кода). Они предлагают делать примерно такие структуры:

```
interface RepositoryModule {
val repository: Repository

class Impl : RepositoryModule {
    override val repository by lazy { Repository.Impl() }
}}
interface RepositoryModule {
    val repository: Repository

    class Impl : Module {
        override val repository = Repository.Impl()
    }
}
interface Context :
    RepositoryModule,
    ServiceModule {

    class Impl(
        repositoryModule: RepositoryModule,
        serviceModule: ServiceModule
    ) : Context,
        RepositoryModule by repositoryModule,
        ServiceModule by serviceModule
}
```

А вообще нет никакой магии в Dagger - посмотрите код который они генерят, его можно писать руками, только долго и муторно.

Comment: вопрос был о том, как не использовать Dagger, ваш ответ мне кажется немного странным :)